# List of used aliases in Tableau

Tags: visualization, tools, tableau

I often get the problem when this or that alias name is already used somewhere, and I can't easily find that variable or aggregation to release the name.

[image]

Is there some place in Tableau where I can view/edit/reset full list of aliases?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally solved the issue.
You should go to:

```
Data –> your_data_source –> Edit Aliases –> Measure Names
```

And see full mapping between variables/aggregations and aliases.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another way of editing alias for a member having multiple aliases:

1. Right click the 'Measure Names' in Dimension panel.
2. Select 'Aliases...'
3. A small edit box appears with all the members having aliases.
4. Edit/update alias for each member, as preferred.
5. Press OK to save any changes made.